# PreOrder Iterative Traversal

Tags: c, tree, binary, iteration, preorder

This Iterative Binary tree traversal keeps giving me segmentation fault errors, im not sure how to assign the pointer for the current variable in the tree to the popped element from it since they are 2 different types.

```
struct BTnode{
     int data;
     struct BTnode* left;
     struct BTnode* right;
     struct BTnode* parent;
}; 
typedef struct BTnode BTnode_t; 


  typedef struct {
      LL_t* list;
  } stack_t;  //stack is created with a Linked List


void preOrderIter(BTnode_t* root)
{
    stack_t* s = stack_create();
    stack_push(s, root->data); 
    BTnode_t* current;

    while (!stack_is_empty(s))
    {
        current = stack_pop(s);
        printf("%d ", current->data); 

        if ( current->right != NULL)
            stack_push(s, current->right->data);

        if ( current->left != NULL)
            stack_push(s, current->left->data); 
    }

    free(s);
}
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `BTnode_t` and `stack_t`?

Comment: BTnode_t is a binary tree struct, and stack_t is a stack struct

Comment: That's not helpful. Can you add the definition to your question? e.g. `struct BTnode_t  {...};`

Comment: `stack_push(s, root->data); ` looks fishy to me. You pop it and  then try to `->` with the data... Seems like you'd want `stack_push(s, root); `, no? If that isn't the problem, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can actually run your code and reproduce the issue. Thank you and welcome to SO!

Comment: In which line the error occurs? if you're not sure use trace the program with debugger and see where it halts.

Comment: the error is given by the 2 if statements ,since i dont give the "current" variable the correct value

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are pushing an integer to stack and then you are trying to pop and assign it to BTNode. You should push BTNode's to the stack, so when you pop it you can get the data. I'm guessing it should be like this;

```
void preOrderIter(BTnode_t* root)
{
  stack_t* s = stack_create();
  stack_push(s, root); 
  BTnode_t* current;

  while (!stack_is_empty(s))
  {
    current = stack_pop(s);
    printf("%d ", current->data); 

    if ( current->right != NULL)
        stack_push(s, current->right);

    if ( current->left != NULL)
        stack_push(s, current->left); 
  }

  free(s);
}
```

This is something you need to fix eventually, but I am not sure if this will fix your segmentation fault error.